# Placing adjectives in front of nouns

Tags: adjectives, possessives

I've a doubt for using adjectives in front of nouns in regards dropping the "s"

I'm a translator (PT>EN) and sometimes the following examples pop out:

(single) Patient Chart / Patient's chart

(plural) Program Characteristics / Program's characteristics

I always see some of these without the "s" and my doubt is the correct usage of the "s"/possessive/etc.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Yes, I think it's more complex than the simple use of "s" for noun/plural cases.

Comment: Those are nouns, not adjectives.

Answer (score 2):

*(single) Patient Chart / Patient's chart*

The first is a compound noun derived from the nouns *patient* and *chart*.  As such, primary stress is on the first part of the compound: "**patient** chart".  The second is a NP (noun phrase) derived from the determiner *patient's* and the noun *chart*.  As such, primary stress is on the last part of the NP: "patient's **chart**". The possessive determiner *patient's* is derived from the NP *patient* and the ending *'s*.

It would also be possible to have a compound noun derived from plural noun *patients* and noun *chart*: "**patients** chart".

*(plural) Program Characteristics / Program's characteristics*

The first is the plural of the compound noun *program characteristic*, with primary stress on *program*. The second is a plural NP with plurality marked by making the head noun *characteristic* plural by adding the ending *s*, *program's* is a determiner, and primary stress is on the last element of the NP: "program's **characteristics**".

There are no adjectives in your examples.  Some people sometimes call the first noun of a compound noun "adjectival", but it isn't really an adjective.  Adjectives are part of NPs, not compound nouns.